# MAUI: Custom ScrollViewHandler for iOS to force resizing when content changes

Tags: maui

We have an issue on iOS where a scrollview size is not updated when it's content changes (hiding or showing children, etc).

I found a fix for this problem [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9209#issuecomment-1327288462) but this handler only fires when the size increases. When we hide the content again the scrollview does not shrink back to it's original size and leaves space at the bottom of the page.

How can I get this to fire when the size decreases as well?

```
ScrollViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("ContentSize", (handler, view) =>
{
  var contentSize = handler.VirtualView.ContentSize;
  var size = new Size(contentSize.Width + view.Padding.HorizontalThickness, contentSize.Height + view.Padding.VerticalThickness);
  handler.PlatformView.UpdateContentSize(size);
  handler.PlatformArrange(handler.PlatformView.Frame.ToRectangle());
});`
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I suspect that is the way iOS scrollview works internally; I don't know if Maui can fix that. You could add a comment on that issue, or create a new maui issue. Try the [workaround mentioned earlier](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9209#issuecomment-1273364304) in that issue: `var content = scrollView.Content; scrollview.Content = null; scrollview.Content = content;`. Do this in your code that changes the content.